# Find and replace regex with jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, replace, find

I am dealing with two query string patterns:
`str='Notebook!!2'` and `str='Notebook+HP+14-d028!!2!!583304'`

Well I need to replace whatever number that comes among "!!N!!"
What matter is that I am receiving this delimiter via cookie.
This is what I am trying...

```
qstr='Notebook!!2' 
//qstr='Notebook+HP+14-d028!!2!!583304'
str=urldecode(qstr);
d=$.cookie('d');
new_str=str.replace(/d*d/g,"d1d");
alert(new_str);
```

I am using jquery-1.9.1.

The expected output is 'Notebook!!1' and 'Notebook+HP+14-d028!!1!!583304', following the above examples

And I am using jquery for other things, that's why I asked for it.

Any tip? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why emphasize jQuery? It looks like you want a pure javascript answer to me.

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex solution:

```
p='Notebook+HP+14-d028!!10!!583304';
H='!!';
r=/^(.*)!{2}([0-9]+)!{2}([0-9]+)$/;
r_to="$1!!1!!$3";
//var a=p.match(r);
var a=p.replace(r,r_to);
alert(a);
```

Old school solution...

```
//str='Notebook!!2' 
str='Notebook+HP+14-d028!!2!!583304'
hash=$.cookie('hash'); //'!!'
i=str.indexOf(hash);
times=str.match(new RegExp(hash,'g')).length;
x=str.substring(0,i+hash.length);
q=x+'1';
if(times>=hash.length*2){
    ii=str.lastIndexOf(hash);
    l=str.length;
    y=str.substring(ii+hash.length,l);
    q=q+hash+y;
}
alert(q);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var new_str = str.replace(/!!\d+!!/g, "");
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my case, I don't know that the delimiter is "!!", that's why I am loading it via cookie. So, the regex must accept the variable inside of it and not the literal "!!" I used in the examples... The delimiter may be "##" or "__" and so on.